# How to add extern alias for three same namespace assemblies in .Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, alias, nuget-package

By Referring below sample, I can able to alias two assemblies. But is this possible to alias three assemblies. if yes, please guide me.

https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/blob/master/ExternPackageReference.Example/ConsoleApp/ConsoleApp.csproj

Thanks in advance.